# Combining 2 Arrays So That They Display Correctly in my URL

Tags: php

I have an array $cat1 including

```
cat1[0]=>16 and cat1[1]=>16.
```

I also have this array:

```
$url_vars = array('text'=>$event->properties['text'],'SearchResultPagerPage'=>$thenextpage);
```

I need to put these combined into this URL function:

```
$this->URL('SearchResult','',$url_vars);
```

So that the resulting URL needs to look like this:

```
/SearchResult.html?text=cat&SearchResultPagerPage=1&cat1[]=1&cat1[]=16
```

Currently, if I combine them, I get this as the resulting combined array:

```
Array
(
    [text] => cat
    [SearchResultPagerPage] => 1
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 16
)
```

and this as the resulting URL:

```
SearchResult.html?&text=cat&SearchResultPagerPage=1&1=16
```

How do I form this so that it says cat1[]=1&cat1[]=16 instead of 1=16?

Thanks very much for any help anyone might offer!!

Comment: Just a suggestion - stop using `array()` and use `[]` instead. `array()` is painful on the eyes.

Comment: Square bracket characters are not allowed in the URI syntax, so your desired result is not 100% possible. You can encode and decode them though

Comment: `$cat1 + $url_vars` should give the right output when combined with `http_build_query()`

Comment: @m59 not everyone has php5.4

Comment: Btw could you do `var_dump($cat1);`? It's somewhat ambiguous now.

Comment: @m59 What if I told you I prefer it the other way around, with such trivial matters this is subject to opinion and if anything `array()` allows the code to be understood quicker at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

If you MUST use the URL function `$this->URL('SearchResult','',$url_vars);` then one idea is to use indices in the cat1 array. That is:

```
$url_vars["cat1[0]"] = 1;
$url_vars["cat1[1]"] = 16;
```

This will result in your query string having

```
...&cat1[0]=1&cat1[1]=16
```

with the []'s probably escaped, but perhaps your server script can properly accommodate these indices. It is worth a try. Otherwise you'll have to generate the URL outside of the URL function, because you can't have a php array with identical keys "cat1[]" but two separate values.

EDIT: One other thing to try in case your URL function is intelligent enough:

```
$url_vars["cat1"] = [1,16];
```

Comment: "you can't have a php array with identical keys "cat1[]" but two separate values." - ehh yes you can.

Comment: @Jack Not unless it's a multidimensional array (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445283/how-to-allow-duplicate-keys-in-php-array) or some other trick. But not directly in the way the OP desires. What did you have in mind?

Comment: I'm assuming that `$var1` has `[16,16]` and then `http_build_query()` would make it work as expected. Unfortunately the OP wasn't very explicit about its contents.