# Reset keys of array elements in php

Tags: php

i want to reset the above as below.

```
$_REQUEST['some_number'] => Array
(
            [0] => 1
            [0_1] => 2
            [0_2] => 3
            [2] => 7
            [2_1] => 8
             [3] => 9
            [3_1] => 10

)
```

to

```
$_REQUEST['some_number'] => Array
(
            [0] => 1
            [0_1] => 2
            [0_2] => 3
            [1] => 7
            [1_1] => 8
            [2] => 9
            [2_1] => 10
)
```

I used array_values for that

`print_r(array_values($_REQUEST['some_number']))`;

i get

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 8
)
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. Arrays can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: Have a look here: [how to allow duplicate keys in php array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445283/how-to-allow-duplicate-keys-in-php-array)

Comment: And when did I say it *is* a duplicate?

Comment: You can use `array_walk()`

Comment: But how ?please give me hints in that direction

Comment: Why the key is `2` when it should be `1_2` ?

Comment: It's not clear from the example what the desired pattern is, in general. Perhaps you could explain the underlying meaning of the unusual choice of keys?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking like this

```
$samp = array("0" => 1,
              "0_1" => 2,
              "0_2" => 3,
              "2" => 7,
              "2_1" => 8,
              "3" => 9,
              "3_1" => 10 );


$samp2 = $samp;
$i=0;
$j=0;
$samp = array();

    foreach($samp2 as $values)
    {
        if($j != 0)
        $samp[$i."_".$j] = $values;
        else
        $samp[$i] = $values; 

        if($j > 1)
        {
            $i++;
            $j=0;
        }
        else
         $j++;
    }

print_r($samp);
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/630da624314a899156939c5c5e4e19ef32a81df7)