# Get column values from an associative array in php

Tags: php, associative-array

I have an array of form:

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    )
);
```

I want output like this :

**EDIT:**

```
 Array
    ( array('first_Name' => John),
      array('first_Name'=> Sally),
      array('first_Name'=> Jane),  
      array('first_Name'=> Peter)
    );
```

Can this be achieved??

Comment: how can be `first_name` as multiple index of array ?

Comment: that has the same keys, that aint possible

Comment: An associative array cant hold the same index key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this since you can't have duplicate keys in an array.

Here is a related question: [How to allow duplicate keys in a PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445283/how-to-allow-duplicate-keys-in-php-array)

This article explains how PHP stores array internally: http://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html.

Answer after your edit:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($records as $value) {
    $arr[] = array('first_name' => $value['first_name']);
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: +1. Or just: `array_walk($records, function ($v, $k) use (&$arr) {  $arr[] = ['first_name' => $v['first_name']]; });`

Comment: And how is this any different from nl-x's answer? Add to that you edited your post after nl-x posted his answer

Comment: @asprin Probably my typing speed is slower than nl-x . While i was typing he answered.

Comment: @asprin: It's not like there are thousand different ways to achieve this :-)

Comment: @asprin For your happiness.It is different now.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your (edited) question like this:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($records as $record)
    $new_array[] = array('first_Name'=>$records['first_name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    )
);

$tmp = array('first_name' => '');
foreach ($records as &$record) {
    $record = array_intersect_key($record, $tmp);
    // or $record = array('first_name' => $record['first_name']);
}
unset($record);

var_dump($records);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to array with in the array means, surely it will generated with index key, like this

```
 Array
    ( '0' => array('first_Name' => John),
      '1' => array('first_Name'=> Sally),
      '2' => array('first_Name'=> Jane),  
      '3' => array('first_Name'=> Peter)
    );
```

Try this one,

```
 foreach($records as $record) {
    $name_array[] = Array('first_Name' =>$record['first_name']);
 }
 print_r($name_array);
```

Your output will be,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_Name] => John
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first_Name] => Sally
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [first_Name] => Jane
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [first_Name] => Peter
        )

)
```

Comment: This is the same as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23776016/1438393) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23775917/1438393). Not sure if having another one with the same content is going to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired output you can use `array_map`, though you can get similar output with `array_column` which is new in PHP 5.5.

#### With `array_map` (http://3v4l.org/v8Y8Z):

```
<?php

$firstNames = array_map(function($record) {
    return ['first_name' => $record['first_name']];
}, $records);
```

---

#### With `array_column` (http://3v4l.org/ohnGu):

```
$firstNames = array_column($records, 'first_name');
```

Note: `array_column` doesn't make subarrays with the `first_name` key.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because you cannot have multiple elements of the same key in an associative array.

Comment: Seriously? This constitutes as an answer?

Comment: @nl-x and Amal _ I wasn't saying the answer is wrong. What I was referring to is a single sentence being posted as an answer. It could well have been posted as a comment

Comment: @asprin : I know that you meant that. So still, why not?

Comment: @nl-x http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer

Comment: @asprin : according to your link it IS an answer. (see #8 in of your link) It says it should be an answer, and should not be reported as NaA (Not an Answer)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
$arr_output = array();
foreach($records as $key=>$arr)
{
    $arr_output['id'][] = $arr['id'];
    $arr_output['first_name'][] = $arr['first_name'];
    $arr_output['last_name'][] = $arr['last_name'];
}

print_r($arr_output['first_name']); // display all first names
print_r($arr_output); // display complete output array.
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2135
            [1] => 3245
            [2] => 5342
            [3] => 5623
        )

    [first_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [1] => Sally
            [2] => Jane
            [3] => Peter
        )

    [last_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Doe
            [1] => Smith
            [2] => Jones
            [3] => Doe
        )

)
```

**[Demo](http://3v4l.org/Y830q)**

Comment: This is not what the OP is askin

Comment: @user2129794 as i commented on your question same key is not possible in array. you can use it as i answered.