# Associative array with similar keys assignment

Tags: php, associative-array

Consider I have associative array with same key values:

```
$arr = {'MessageID' =>1 ,'MessageID' =>5 , 'MessageID' => 8};
```

Now I want every call to `function foo()` which will insert a new key value of `'MessageID'=>integer`

How can we do that without overriding other existing key values pairs?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445283/how-to-allow-duplicate-keys-in-php-array AFAIK, the array keys can't be duplicated, so the question is, how you ended up with the sample array you gave use...

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in an array. Also your sample with curly braces is not valid php syntax. Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many answerers before, you can't have keys with the same string in the array in PHP. If you want to represent multiple values per key I use something like this:

```
$arr = ['MessageID' => [1, 5, 8]];
```

You would append to MessageID with this code:

```
$arr['MessageId'][] = 10;
```

Then it would look like this:

```
['MessageID' => [1, 5, 8, 10]]
```

This worked well for me with HTTP headers and other things which are key value based, but can have multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

In php array, you can not insert multiple values with same index.
If you want to use it then you can use it with following manner

`$MessageID = array(1,5,8);`
and 
`$MessageID[] = $newValue;` to insert new value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an array with duplicate keys.

A better implementation would be to have an array called $messageIDs and save the actual values in the array:

```
$messageIDs = array (1, 5, 8);
```

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in comments, you cannot have duplicate keys in an array. Also your sample with curly braces is not valid php syntax.

Perhaps you need a multidimentional array:

```
$arr = [['messageID'=>1],['messageID'=>5],['messageID'=>8]];
```

in which case you would add another value like so:

```
$arr[] = ['messageID'=>11];
```