# Finding common words in an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a **string**:

```
Fragrances, Beauty & Health (153)
    Skin Care (146)
    Make Up (10)
    Health Care & Instruments (1)
    Hair Care (1)
```

I'm converting it into an array:

```
$formatted = array_map('trim', preg_split("/[()]+/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Fragrances, Beauty & Health
    [1] => 153
    [2] => Skin Care
    [3] => 146
    [4] => Make Up
    [5] => 10
    [6] => Health Care & Instruments
    [7] => 1
    [8] => Hair Care
    [9] => 1
)
```

... what should I do to achieve the **desired** result:

```
Array
(
    [Fragrances, Beauty & Health] => 153
    [Skin Care] => 146
    [Make Up] => 10
    [Health Care & Instruments] => 1
    [Hair Care] => 1
)
```

Comment: You can just loop through the 1st array and make the same 2nd,are you OK with that?

Comment: @Varun Not really, I could've done that way but I need this to be efficient cause I'll be doing this on every request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

First just [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your string by each line, then go through each element with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and split it either by `(` or `)`.

After this you can simply use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to use the first column as key and the second one as value.

```
<?php

    $arr = array_column(array_map(function($v){
        return array_map("trim", preg_split("/[()]+/", $v, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
    }, explode(PHP_EOL, $str)), 1, 0);

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [Fragrances, Beauty & Health] => 153
    [Skin Care] => 146
    [Make Up] => 10
    [Health Care & Instruments] => 1
    [Hair Care] => 1
)
```

**EDIT:**

You can't have duplicate keys, so if you want to keep the one with the highest value you could do something like this:

```
$arr = array_map(function($v){
    $arr = array_map("trim", preg_split("/[()]+/", $v, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
    if(!isset($arr[1]))
        $arr[1] = 0;
    return $arr;
}, explode(PHP_EOL, $str));

usort($arr, function($a, $b){
    return $a[1] - $b[1];
});

$arr = array_column($arr, 1, 0);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Almost works, but something trips it .. please see: http://pastebin.com/ZHX2tGrn (Count is all wrong)

Comment: @3zzy My code works fine. You just can't have duplicate keys! You can have 2 elements with the key: `Face Care` or `Skin Care`

Comment: Ah heck, didn't notice. Hmm.. technically correct, but I'll have to find a solution for this now. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @3zzy Want to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5445310/3933332 ?

Comment: Would work if I could just keep the one with the higher value, and discard the others.

Comment: @3zzy updated my code to keep the key with the highest value

Comment: Just one more thing please: It throws an error `Undefined offset: 1 in` if the list item doesn't have a count at the end in parenthesis. Can it be ignored or given a `0` ?

Comment: @3zzy updated the code under the edit to check if the index 1 isset, and if not set it to 0

Comment: `usort` sorts in asc order, I tried arsort but it changes the order on some arrays. Would it be possible to change it desc using usort itself?

Comment: @3zzy Just swap `$a` with `$b` in the anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = explode("\n",$array);

$desireArray = array();
foreach($arr as $value)
{
    $val = explode("(",$value);
    $desireArray[trim($val[0])] = trim($val[1],")");
}

print_R($desireArray);
```