# combine two arrays has same keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like

```
$sele_itmid = Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 4
)
$fltrd_serl_batch = Array
(
    [0] => SAL121
    [1] => SAL122
    [2] => SAL 145
    [3] => M121
    [4] => M122
)
```

At this time i need to combine them like `$sele_itmid` values as keys `$fltrd_serl_batch` some thing like

```
array(
    [1] => SAL121
    [1] => SAL122
    [1] => SAL 145
    [4] => M121
    [4] => M122
)
```

I know cant use `array_combine` because it wont accept duplicate keys. what is the other way to do this? Is there any array function to do this?

Comment: No, there is not, arrays **CANNOT** have duplicate keys.

Comment: can't you have ? array(
    [1] => array( [0]=>SAL121 , [1]=> SAL122,  [2]=>SAL 145
...)

Comment: poosible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445283/how-to-allow-duplicate-keys-in-php-array

Comment: You could make it multidimensional to overcome this? as in: `array('0' => array('SAL121','SAL1212'), [...]` - now all the index's at 0 will be in an array sharing the same index

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you explained what you are trying to achieve by combining these 2 arrays, then we could suggest something useful

Comment: Please [do a search](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+array+same+key) before posting a question that is obviously a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Associative Array Duplicate Key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879132/php-associative-array-duplicate-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$itm_btch = array_map(function($key, $val) {return array($key=>$val);}, $sele_itmid, $fltrd_serl_batch);

print_r($itm_btch );
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => SAL122
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => SAL 145
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [4] => M121
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [4] => M122
        )

)
```