# split an array into groups every time there is a different group_id number in php

Tags: php

a dynamic array sorted from database that have some of multi similar group id's and some different ones something like this :

```
 $sourcearray = array(
 array(id => 1  , value => 'text'),
 array(id => 1  , value => 'text'),
 array(id => 1  , value => 'text'),
 array(id => 1  , value => 'text'),

 array(id => 2  , value => 'text'),
 array(id => 3  , value => 'text'),

 array(id => 4  , value => 'text'),
 array(id => 4  , value => 'text')
 );
```

i would like to split them into groups that have the same group id
something like :

```
 $group1 = array(
 array(id => 1  , value => 'text'),
 array(id => 1  , value => 'text'),
 array(id => 1  , value => 'text'),
 array(id => 1  , value => 'text')
 );

 $group2 = array(
  array(id => 2  , value => 'text')
 );    

 $group3 = array(
  array(id => 3  , value => 'text')
 ); 

 $group4 = array(
  array(id => 4  , value => 'text'),
  array(id => 4  , value => 'text')
 );
```

this id is no unique and this arrangements and group id's are not static they could be different depend on the website admin panel settings

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same key on an array.

Comment: Sorry, but those simply cannot exist in PHP (the source array would never look like that). keys and indexes are unique. PHP will only keep the last one defined.

Comment: sorry my bad i forget to tell you that this is a result from a database and those keys are registered as group_id and its not unique , i'll edit my quistion , very sorry for that confusion

Comment: Are you sure it isn't something more like `$sourcearray = array(
 array(1   =>  'value'),` etc?

Comment: @Don'tPanic , yeah exactly i was confused and hurry writing the question , i edit it now thanks for reminding me  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would recommend doing this is to group your results in a single array using the specific column you want to group by as a key while you fetch the rows from your query.

```
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $result[$row['id']][] = $row;
}
```

This will produce a result like this:

```
$groups = [
    1 => [
        ['id' => 1, 'value' => 'text'],
        ['id' => 1, 'value' => 'text'],
        ['id' => 1, 'value' => 'text'],
        ['id' => 1, 'value' => 'text']
    ],
    2 => [
        ['id' => 2, 'value' => 'text']
    ],
    3 => [
        ['id' => 3, 'value' => 'text']
    ],
    4 => [
        ['id' => 4, 'value' => 'text'],
        ['id' => 4, 'value' => 'text']
    ]
];
```

which will be easier to use than separate variables for each group.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` to summarise the date into an associative array. You can use `extract` to import variables into the current symbol table from an array

```
$sourcearray = array(
     array("id" => 1  , "value" => 'text'),
     array("id" => 1  , "value" => 'text'),
     array("id" => 1  , "value" => 'text'),
     array("id" => 1  , "value" => 'text'),
     array("id" => 2  , "value" => 'text'),
     array("id" => 3  , "value" => 'text'),
     array("id" => 4  , "value" => 'text'),
     array("id" => 4  , "value" => 'text')
);

$result = array_reduce($sourcearray, function($c, $v){
    $c[ 'group' . $v['id'] ][] = $v;
    return $c;
}, array());

extract($result);  //Optional. If you want to use variable like $group1, $group2 etc
```

Now you can use `$group1`, `$group2` etc

Doc: [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php), [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Comment: Upvoted for answering the question as-is rather than projecting your opinions like I did

Comment: Nice answer too. Just be aware that `extract()` use `EXTR_OVERWRITE` by default and could eventually override existing variable.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed in the comments, you can't have an array with repeated keys in PHP. The last key attribution will override the previous ones. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445283/how-to-allow-duplicate-keys-in-php-array) might help you with alternatives.