# Array merging product with same ID

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I coded this to get an array with all product in the order

```
$sync_data = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($request['product_id']); $i++) {
        $sync_data[$request->input('product_id')[$i]] = [
            'sequence_no' => $i+1,
            'type' => 'order',
            'quantity' => $request->input('quantity')[$i],
            'listprice' => $request->input('listprice')[$i],
            'discount_percent' => NULL,
            'discount_amount' => $request->input('discount_amount')[$i],
            'comment' => $request->input('comment')[$i],
            'description' => '',
            'tax1' => $request->input('tax1')[$i],
            'tax2' => $request->input('tax2')[$i],
            'tax3' => NULL,
            'tax4' => NULL,
            'campaign_id' => $request->input('campaign_id')[$i]
        ];            
    }
```

but it is merging the product with the same ID, so i am getting this

```
array:2 [▼
  194 => array:13 [▶]
  191 => array:13 [▶]
]
```

and i want this

```
array:2 [▼
  194 => array:13 [▶]
  194 => array:13 [▶]
  191 => array:13 [▶]
]
```

can someone please explain to me what i am missing ?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: You can't have multiple values with the same key in an array. What would you expect `$sync_data[194]` to give you in your example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow duplicate keys in php array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445283/how-to-allow-duplicate-keys-in-php-array)

Comment: If you want duplicate entries in an array, you can't use the same key. You could have an indexed array, and set `'product_id' => $request->input('product_id')[$i]` as one of your array keys, etc.

Comment: I just add in my order 3 product in total where 2 product are identical so they have same ID (194) so my code is merging the 2 product and i dont know ho should i code this one.

Comment: where should i insert this ? 'product_id' => $request->input('product_id')[$i]

Comment: You can change the ID of one of the product? why both product have the same ID? you will have a lot of issues if you have the same ID for multiple products.

Comment: You should insert that in the same place you're setting every other array value...

Comment: no i can't its the same product so they have same ID

Comment: Yes, you can, but you have to remove `$sync_data[$request->input('product_id')[$i]]`, it would just be `$sync_data[] = [ ... ]`. That's what I mean when I say you can have an indexed array instead of an associative array.

Comment: but how can i attach them to the order ? 
$order->products()->attach($sync_data);

Comment: *Sigh*... Well that's not part of your original question... Also, you can't attach the same data multiple times; you'd end up with duplicate data in your database, or one would simply overwrite the second one. I think you need to rethink your approach to all of this.

Comment: its a sample order product relation with pivot column i think it should be with this way but im missing something i will found it and tell you =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it =) thank all for your help

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request['product_id']); $i++) {
            $sync_data[] = [
                'sequence_no' => $i+1,
                'type' => 'order',
                'quantity' => $request->input('quantity')[$i],
                'listprice' => $request->input('listprice')[$i],
                'discount_percent' => NULL,
                'discount_amount' => $request->input('discount_amount')[$i],
                'comment' => $request->input('comment')[$i],
                'description' => '',
                'tax1' => $request->input('tax1')[$i],
                'tax2' => $request->input('tax2')[$i],
                'tax3' => NULL,
                'tax4' => NULL,
                'product_id' => $request->input('product_id')[$i],
                'campaign_id' => $request->input('campaign_id')[$i]
            ];    

        }
        foreach ($sync_data as $product) {            
            $order->products()->attach($product['product_id'], $product);
        }
```